# How can I accessed upsertedId when using updateOne in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, save, insert-update, upsert

I have new data that I want to insert in my `array` of `blog` (My collection look like this - shown below):-

```
{
    _id: 0,
    // other vars here...,
    blog: [
        {
            _id: 0,
            title: 'Article 1'
        },
        // add new article here
    ]
}
```

Right now I'm able to add new `article` in my `blog array` with the code shown below:-

```
const query = {}
const update = { $push: { blog: inputData } }
const options = { upsert: true }

All.updateOne(query, update, options)
.then(result => {
    res.redirect(`/article/${result.upsertedId}`) // read MongoDB documentation that I can get the newly inserted data ID by using result.upsertedId
})
.catch(err => res.redirect(`/`)
```

But I can't seem to get the `ID` of the newly inserted data into my collection. Using `result.upsertedId` returns me `undefined` instead. According to the code above, I need the `ID` in order to redirect user to the new article page of that `ID`.

Here's the documentation telling that it will `return upsertedId` [updateOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/actions/collection.updateOne/)

this is the `result` I get when console.log it (There's no `upsertedId` anywhere in it)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Print your result to confirm an ID is being received, your result is likely something similar to this:

```
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }
```

You could try using [collection.findOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/actions/collection.findOneAndUpdate/) and retrieve upsertedId from that result

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass new: true in the option to get the id of the updated document
i.e

```
const query = {}
const update = { $push: { blog: inputData } }
const options = { upsert: true, new: true  }

All.updateOne(query, update, options)
.then(result => {
    //result is your upserted document
    console.log("Upserted document : ", result);// try getting your upserted _id 
        //from this result 
    res.redirect(`/article/${result.upsertedId}`) // change //result.upsertedId into result._id or result.id whatever you get into //your result
})
.catch(err => res.redirect(`/`)
```

Comment: I added `new: true` in `const options = { upsert: true, new: true }`. But nothing change. And my `result` look like this(shown in above question)

Comment: Which mongo connector/npm are you using?

Comment: I'm using Node JS with mongoose package version 5.9.20

Comment: OK fine, actually result is a mongoose object so in order to get plain JSON either you user result.toObject() https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject or use lean (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-updateOnet) instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is not applicable for nested documents.

What you are doing is an update operation.

Doc says

> The _id value of the document inserted by an upsert operation. This value is only present when the upsert option is enabled and the update query does not match any documents.

And your query results in update operation. That's why you are getting `nModified`.

One option is that you can use `findOneAndUpdate` with option `returnNewDocument` option true.

Comment: This one returns me the `whole` collection data. But not the newly inserted data. Is it suppose to be like that?

Comment: No, How did you try? It will return only updated document?

Comment: I change my `const options = { upsert: true }` to `const options = { returnNewDocument: true }`. And `console.log(result)`, it gave me the whole collections but not the updated / newly created data. Is it because I've nested document? That's why it returns me the whole documents instead of just the blog array.

Comment: Can you paste the result of the query?

Comment: it gave me basically everything that I have in the collection (like the example of my collection stated in my question), `_id: 0, some other vars..., blog: [ {_id: 0, some other vars here...}, {_id: 1, some other vars here...}, {_id: 2, some other vars here...}]`. All except the newly/updated document

Comment: What you mentioned is one document not entire collection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219202/discussion-between-lala-and-gibbs).